# Gnome-shell will not launch Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, gnome, window-manager

When I log into the Gnome session, the shell does not launch.

In terminal I get the following:

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ gnome-shell
Window manager warning: Screen 0 on display ":0" already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$
```

How can I find the current window manager?

If I change the window manager will it break Unity?

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Ubuntu 13.04 64bit
Gnome 3.8

EDIT:

Removed Compiz and Unity, then Gnome-shell worked... Guess it's a conflict somewhere

Comment: try to reconfigure your login manager using sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed Compiz and Unity, then Gnome-shell worked... Guess it's a conflict somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try running gnome-shell with the `-r` (replace) option:

```
gnome-shell --replace
```

or

```
gnome-shell -r
```

should replace the current running window manager (if that is what you want!). If you want to use gnome-shell by default, reconfigure your login manager with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` (as suggested by Josh) to have the option of selecting gnome-shell session at your login screen.

Comment: Thanks tried this, but the shell wouldn't start. I installed KDE, and removed Compiz, then it worked, but lost Unity. I may stick with Kubuntu, seems ok.. Thanks again